# Calling Approval Process from Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, approval-process

I have an existing `approval process` and I am calling it from a `flow`. The `approval process` has logic to send email when it's initiated (Initial Submission Actions) and when it's approved/denied (Final Approval Actions). The flow is working fine and approval process is working too, but I am not receiving those emails after the approval process is initiated or approved/denied.

I have checked the `Deliverability` and it's `"All Action"`.

My question is can we trigger the email via `approval process` or do I have to add `"Send Email"` action from flow only.

Comment: A few prodding questions: Is this in a sandbox? What kind of Flow / what initiates the Flow (screen, record-triggered, platform event, scheduled, etc)? Can you send out emails manually using the email composer in the activity component?

Answer (score 1):

When a flow runs, its context is either the User who launched it or, in some cases, the 'Autoproc User'. If the approval process sends email normally, but the email sends stop working when the approval process is invoked through a flow, the issue is that the context coming from the Flow isn't cleared to send email.

if the flow is being launched automatically, by a schedule or trigger:
Check these two values and make sure that you have assigned a user with full system administrator access rights.
[image]

if the flow is launched by a user, try elevating its permissions with System Context: [image]